# How often should I clean the drains in my house?

Tags: drains

we moved into our house three years ago. The drains were new, and now three years after I'm interested if we should cleen them.

Comment: Is there some reason you would expect a cleaning might be necessary? Is performance reduced in some way? Is there something about your home in particular that might necessitate extra maintenance?

Comment: Which drains are you talking about? Sink, floor, etc?

Comment: This might be slightly off topic, but you would probably be interested to know that the septic tank should be pumped every 3 - 5 years.

Comment: 1)As Daniel asked, which drains(sewage)? 2)How old is your house? 3)What State/Province do you live in? 4) Are there any trees whose canopy sizes, when doubled, would overhang your house?

Answer (score 5):

Normal modern drain installations do not require any regular cleaning. If you notice a clog/slowdown or gurgling, a targeted cleaning may help. But if your concern is buildup of material inside of drain/waste/vent pipes, this is rarely a concern. Sometimes after 50-100 years there can be enough buildup to cause a problem. But preemptive cleaning of drains is not typically worth it.

Comment: I would agree, with plastic pipe if it was "snaked" now it gets scratched, chemicals , I haven't found them to work unless plugged and then all the caustic goes in to the sewer. +